# JSF error al enviar valores al managedbean

Tags: java, base-de-datos, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Buenas tardes, estoy aprendiendo Java EE y entre practica y practica me he encontrado con un error que no puedo resolver, es pero me puedan colaborar para seguir con mi proceso de aprendizaje. El error que me da es el siguiente:

> /index.xhtml @23,111 value="#{alumno.nombre}": The class 'videotutoriales.PrimeFaces.alumno' does not have a readable property 'nombre'.

he intentado cambiar las anotaciones pero no se me ocurre que puede estar mal, aquí les dejo parte de mi código:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

```
<body>

    <ui:composition template="./plantilla.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="top">
            <h2>Datos personalizados de alumnos</h2>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form>
                <p:messages/>
                <p:panel header="Escribir informacion del alumno">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel for="nombre" value="Nombre " styleClass="requiredLbl"/>
                        <h:inputText id="nombre" label="Nombre" value="#{alumno.nombre}" required="true"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="primerApellido" value="Primer Apellido"/>
                        <h:inputText id="primerApellido" label="Primer Apellido" value="#{alumno.primerApellido}"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="segundoApellido" value="Segundo Apellido"/>
                        <h:inputText id="segundoApellido" label="Segundo Apellido" value="#{alumno.segundoApellido}"/>

                        <h:outputLabel for="fechaNacimiento" value="Fecha de Nacimiento"/>
                        <p:calendar id="fechaNacimiento" value="#{alumno.fechaNacimiento}" 
                                    showOn="button" navigator="true"/>
                        <h:panelGroup/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Enviar"
                                         action="#{alumnoController.salvarAlumno}"
                                         ajax="false"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>

            </h:form>

        </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>

</body>
```

y el managedbean que estoy usando es solo getter y setter y se los dejo a continuación:

```
package videotutoriales.PrimeFaces;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date; 
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped; 
import javax.inject.Named;

/**
 *
 * @author Ana Sofia
 */
@Named(value = "alumno")
@RequestScoped
public class alumno {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of alumno
 */
public alumno() {
}

private String nombre;
private String primerApellido;
private String segundoApellido;
private Date fechaNacimiento;
private final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

public String getFechaNacimiento(){

    String fechaNacimientoFormateada = "";

    if(fechaNacimiento != null){

        fechaNacimientoFormateada = sdf.format(fechaNacimiento);
    }

    return fechaNacimientoFormateada;
}

public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento){

    this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
}

public String nombre(){

    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre){

    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getPrimerApellido(){

    return primerApellido;
}

public void setPrimerApellido(String primerApellido){

    this.primerApellido = primerApellido;
}

public String getSegundoApellido(){

    return segundoApellido;
}

public void setSegundoApellido(String segundoApellido){

        this.segundoApellido = segundoApellido;
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un error en el método `get` del atributo `nombre`. Tienes esto:

```
public String nombre(){
    return nombre;
}
```

Y debería ser así:

```
public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó a resolver mi problema.

Comment: @HildemyBorely por favor considera [aceptar una respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227)

Answer (score 1):

Debes conformar un getter completo, el nombre no tiene un get completo, un get completo es una funcion con get   en este caso public string getNombre(){}